# Close JS Menu on ESC

Tags: jquery, html, css, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I am working on a simple slide-in menu system. I'd like to be able to close a menu by hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

Here's my current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/3w539Lct/3/

Line 126 of my Javascript, you can see:

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
            if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
                $(".menu-wrap").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
```

However, this doesn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: `menu-wrap` is a `div` what do you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reused some of your existing functions and variables. 
This should be correct.

The element $(."menu-wrap") is a **div**, and **doesn't have a checked property**. You need to **add** the logic of hiding the menu on escape button press.

```
     $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
        if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
             isOpen && classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
        }
    });
```

Here's a working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3w539Lct/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the `toggleMenu` on the condition it's `isOpen`.
like so:

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
        isOpen && toggleMenu();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3w539Lct/7/

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 27) {
     toggleMenu();
 }// escape key maps to keycode `27`
});
```

hope this helps