# Closing menu with escape key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery toggle menu and currently I can only close it if I pressed the X button. What I want to achieve is to have it close using escape key as well. Would appreciate any help I can get. Below is the sample of codes used.

HTML

```
 <section class="menu-section">
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-hide">
        <ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Here's the JS.

```
$(".menu-toggle").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $('.menu-section').toggleClass("on");
  $("nav ul").toggleClass('hidden');  
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close JS Menu on ESC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028740/close-js-menu-on-esc)

Answer (score 2):

Key code for <kbd>Esc</kbd> is `27`, So you can ask if it pressed, and if it is, then ask if our `nav ul` Dont have the class `hidden`

```js
$(".menu-toggle").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $('.menu-section').toggleClass("on");
  $("nav ul").toggleClass('hidden');  
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
       if (!$("nav ul").hasClass("hidden")) {$("nav ul").toggleClass("hidden")}
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="menu-section">
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-hide">
        <ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the keyup event: Key code for Esc is 27

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".menu-toggle").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $('.menu-section').toggleClass("on");
  $("nav ul").toggleClass('hidden');  
});
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("section.menu-section").toggle();
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
     //also check here some another stuff like menu already opend or not
       $("section.menu-section").hide();
    }
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="menu-section">
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-hide">
        <ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>

<button id='btn'>HideShow Menu </button>
```